# How to retreive and manage MULTIPLE Azure AD tokens from an ASP.Net MVC 5 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory, access-token

I have an ASP.Net MVC 5 web appication that uses Azure AD to authenticate. We currently use the OWIN and OpenID Connect library to implement the sign-in and the retrieval and management of an access token for an API resource that the web app needs to call.

This has been working fine for the past year, but now we have the requirement to obtain an additional token from another 3rd party resource. The OpenID Connect library uses the Implicit Grant Flow which DOES NOT provide a refresh token and does not allow scopes from multiple resources, I am guessing that we will need to use the Authorization Code Flow to achieve this but cannot find any samples or libraries that support this.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to the correct approach and libraries to use to authenticate an MVC web application with Azure AD and to acquire and manage access tokens for multiple API resources?

It is likely that this application may need to access a 3rd API resource down the road as well.

Answer (score 0):

Implicit flow is for browser-embedded apps, Auth Code grant for regular web apps and native apps. You cannot just inter-change them with each other. If you are using ADAL/MSAL for a SPA app, it already 'knows' how to request additional tokens when you call different APIs (urls) - the [endpoint mapping structure](https://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/10/28/adal-javascript-and-angularjs-deep-dive/) you pass to ADAL/MSAL at initialization tells it which url corresponds to which resource app id. It will then use existing AAD cookies to silently get new tokens.

IMHO, a more secure approach is to have your SPA always call it's own back-end app (from where it was served) and let that app call other APIs. Tokens obtained using the Implict flow are explicitly less secure (they are in the browser) so callees need to worry whether they are not being called with an easily replicated token.

Comment: The app is not a SPA app, but a regular web app that needs to make API calls from the serverside code. I would like some pointers or an example of how to set up authorization and obtaining and managing tokens for multiple APIs. I don't believe that this can be done with the OWIN/OpenID Connect library which I am currently using to do authentication and obtaining a single access token.

Comment: Yes, you can do it from a regular web app (your mention of Implicit Flow made me think yours was a SPA). You use Auth Code Grant to get the id_token and authorization code. Use the authorization code to request a token to one of your apps. You can then use its refresh token to get access tokens to other APIs. Alternatively, use the auth code to get an access token to yourself and then use extension flow to get tokens to other APIs.

Comment: If using the V2 AAD endpoint, make sure to include all the scopes (all APIs) in the initial request for auth code and then use only scopes for one API in converting it to individual API access tokens.

Comment: The one scenario where things get much more complex is B2C. B2C does not support extension flows or asking for auth code for multiple resources. With B2C you will need to re-run the initial auth code request for each API. Makes for some tricky coding.